# Deriving normalization for the shifted associated Legendre function

Tags: orthogonality, legendre-polynomials, legendre-functions

Where can I find a solution for this integral:

$ \int_{a}^{b} P^m_l(c_1x + c_2b)P^{m'}_l(c_1x + c_2b)\,d(c_1x + c_2b)$, most solutions only solves for the interval [-1,1]. Of course I am looking for the normalization of such set of functions.

Many thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything?